# Automate iOS MDM profile testing

Tags: ios, testing, integration-testing, mdm

I would like to write an automation tests for a solution with iOS MDM profile and application, installed by policy in profile.
User installs MDM profile by clicking a link in email and after that, the profile automatically install the application. I'd like to test that profile is installed correctly, the app was installed and application settings was configured through profile.

As I know, iOS UI Automation doesn't cover a parts of interaction with operation system (like, install and remove profiles). Right now I have only one approach for this task with [sikulix](http://www.sikulix.com/) based on the image recognition of mobile device screen (shared with VNC, which requires jailbreak).

Is there any other tools that can help to test such integration logic between iOS as operation system and application?

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is jailbroken then you can directly check whether a config profile or application installed. Both are just files on the file system.

Frankly, I don't remember the path to them. However, if you install a file browser you can find them